# Dask DataFrame: Resample over groupby object with multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, castra

I have the following dask dataframe created from Castra:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.from_castra('data.castra', columns=['user_id','ts','text'])
```

Yielding:

```
                      user_id / ts                  / text
ts
2015-08-08 01:10:00   9235      2015-08-08 01:10:00   a
2015-08-08 02:20:00   2353      2015-08-08 02:20:00   b
2015-08-08 02:20:00   9235      2015-08-08 02:20:00   c
2015-08-08 04:10:00   9235      2015-08-08 04:10:00   d
2015-08-08 08:10:00   2353      2015-08-08 08:10:00   e
```

**What I'm trying to do is:**

1. Group by `user_id` and `ts`
2. Resample it over a 3-hour period
3. In the resampling step, any merged rows should concatenate the texts

**Example output:**

```
                                text
user_id   ts
9235      2015-08-08 00:00:00   ac
          2015-08-08 03:00:00   d
2353      2015-08-08 00:00:00   b
          2015-08-08 06:00:00   e
```

I tried the following:

```
df.groupby(['user_id','ts'])['text'].sum().resample('3H', how='sum').compute()
```

And got the following error:

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex
```

I tried passing `set_index('ts')` in the pipe but it doesn't seem to be an attribute of `Series`.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

**TL;DR**

If it makes the problem easier, I'm also able to change the format of the Castra DB I created too. The implementation I have currently was largely taken from [this](http://blaze.pydata.org/blog/2015/09/08/reddit-comments/) great post.

I set the index (in the `to_df()` function) as follows:

```
df.set_index('ts',drop=False,inplace=True)
```

And have:

```
  with BZ2File(os.path.join(S.DATA_DIR,filename)) as f:
     batches = partition_all(batch_size, f)
     df, frames = peek(map(self.to_df, batches))
     castra = Castra(S.CASTRA, template=df, categories=categories)
     castra.extend_sequence(frames, freq='3h')
```

Here are the resulting dtypes:

```
ts                datetime64[ns]
text                      object
user_id                  float64
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we can assume that each `user-id` group can fit in memory then I recommend using dask.dataframe to do the outer-groupby but then using pandas to do the operations within each group, something like the following.

```
def per_group(blk):
    return blk.groupby('ts').text.resample('3H', how='sum')

df.groupby('user_id').apply(per_group, columns=['ts', 'text']).compute()
```

This decouples two hard things into the two different projects

1. Shuffling all of the user-ids together into the right groups is handled by dask.dataframe
2. Doing the complex datetime resampling within each group is handled explicitly by pandas.

Ideally dask.dataframe would write the per-group function for you automatically.  At the moment dask.dataframe does not intelligently handle multi-indexes, or resampling on top of multi-column groupbys, so the automatic solution isn't yet available.  Still, it's quite possible to fall back to pandas for the per-block computation while still using dask.dataframe to prepare the groups accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the great solution. Is your use of `apply` a recommended  method to access pandas functionality that isn't present in dask (assuming the block can fit into memory)? This would be a huge help to by-pass the current limitations of dask dataframes!

Comment: Generally, yes.  The groupby-apply approach will always work, it just won't be as fast as pure dask.dataframe solutions.  Dask.dataframe will never achieve the full breadth of  pandas so escape hatches are really important.

Comment: you've already helped me a lot on this question, but could you also tell me what the resulting object type is? When I print `type(df)` it gives me `dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame` but I'm unable to then run `.to_castra` or get `values`, etc. Is the behavior changed? Let me know if I should post this as a new question. Many thanks again!

Comment: Everything should be fine.  You might want to check that the `columns=` kwarg is correct.  I'm mostly guessing at what the resulting columns would be.

Comment: Add `, meta=('int32')` in `apply` to prevent Warning.

Answer (score -1):

Try converting your index to a DatetimeIndex like this:

```
import datetime
# ...
df.index = dd.DatetimeIndex(df.index.map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
# ...
```